# What conditions are necessary for an ideal in a Dedekind domain to be principal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, dedekind-domain

Let $R$ be a Dedekind domain that isn't necessarily a PID. Let $I$ be a nonzero ideal generated by $a_1 , a_2$.

What conditions are necessary for $I=(a)$ for some $a \in R$?

Comment: Does your ring have an identity?

Comment: integral domain means a commutative ring with unity and has no zero divisor

Comment: Oh, sorry. I add condition: R is dedekind domain

Comment: In that case I believe you need to show $\exists$ $r_1,r_2\in R$ such that $a=a_1r_1+a_2r_2$, which implies $(a)\subseteq(a_1,a_2)$; and you also need to show $\exists$ $r_1,r_2\in R$ such  that $a_1=r_1a$ and $a_2=r_2a$.  Thus $(a)\supseteq(a_1,a_2)$.

Comment: Incidentally, I believe every ideal in a Dedekind domain can be generated by at most two elements.

Comment: $I \supseteq (a)\iff I\mid (a)\iff IJ = (a).\,$ If so $\ |I| |J| = |a|\,$ so $\, I = (a)\iff |I| = |a|,\,$ i.e. $I$ is principal iff it contains an element of the same norm.

Comment: Thank you. Then how to choose two elements $x$,$y$ $\in R$ such that $I=(x,y)$ is not principal?. check all $N(px+qy)$? I don't know.